# Python Pexpect expect getting timedout error

Tags: python, pexpect

expect funtion is getting timed out. I am posting my code and also the steps when done manually

```
import pexpect
from pexpect import popen_spawn
child = popen_spawn.PopenSpawn('tibemsadmin -server localhost:7222 -user admin -password admin', cwd='C:/tibco/ems/8.5 - Copy/bin')
out = child.sendline('delete queue zzzzzzz')
child.expect('Are you sure (yes,no)?')
print(out)
```

When Done Manually:

```
C:\tibco\ems\8.5 - Copy\bin>tibemsadmin -server localhost:7222 -user admin -password admin

TIBCO Enterprise Message Service Administration Tool.
Copyright 2003-2019 by TIBCO Software Inc.
All rights reserved.

Version 8.5.1 V4 9/12/2019

Connected to: tcp://localhost:7222
Type 'help' for commands help, 'exit' to exit:
tcp://localhost:7222> delete queue zzzzzzz
Are you sure (yes,no)? yes
Queue 'zzzzzzz' has been deleted
tcp://localhost:7222>
```

Error:

```
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pexpect\expect.py", line 144, in timeout
    raise exc
pexpect.exceptions.TIMEOUT: <pexpect.popen_spawn.PopenSpawn object at 0x019AE790>
searcher: searcher_re:
    0: re.compile(b'Are you sure (yes,no)?')
<pexpect.popen_spawn.PopenSpawn object at 0x019AE790>
searcher: searcher_re:
    0: re.compile(b'Are you sure (yes,no)?')
```

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: I have added it. Let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: error shows that it threats text `Are you sure (yes,no)?` as regex - but in regex some chars have special meaning - ie. `( )` or `?`  - and then it may need `\( \)` or `\?` to threat them as normal char.

Comment: child.expect('Are')
Even this didn't work

Comment: Can we PIPE the output from the child process? and check it?  if you know how to do this? let me know

Comment: using `pexpect.spawn()` I can use `print( child.before )` to see it. In source code of [PopenSpawn](https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/pexpect/popen_spawn.html) I see it already use `PIPE` - but you can use this source code to create own class with modification.

Comment: I found [(pexpect.popen_spawn.PopenSpawn(ssh commend) didn't work on windows #414)](https://github.com/pexpect/pexpect/issues/414) and maybe your code also has problem on Windows. Someone write that `paramiko-expect` works better.